# javascript on rasperry pi

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I'm not sure where to ask this, but I just got a raspberry pi and set it up as a web server. I am running apache 2 on it with php 5 and mysql all set up. That is all running fine but I put a project on it that runs some javascript but the javascript is not running. I have everything on a seperate machine runing x-ampp and it is running perfectly. Any one have any ideas on where I should look to solve this issue?

Comment: JavaScript is client-side, not server-side. You need a web browser that supports JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client browser

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "javascript is not running"? Do you use the same browser to test it on both servers?

Comment: I have both of them open in the exact same browser at the exact same time. The one on the x-amp server is running the javascript and the one on the pi is not. I know that javascript is client side but I call the js files from a php file. Is it possible something is wrong with the php install on the pi and it is not calling the js files?

Comment: @josh Ever heard of NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I am running x-amp on windows and obviously the pi is running a linux based OS. PHP on Windows is not case sensitive and loaded jquery with no problem where PHP on Linux is case sensitive and would not load the file because it had a capital Q.